# Word Instance is created with /Automation switch when word is created using CoCreateInstance method

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ms-office

I am creating a instance of word by calling [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) method with CLSID of word. When i create the Instance, the instance is automatically created using the /Automation -embedding command line switch. Wanted to know if there a way to create word instance using CoCreateInstance method and without the /automation -embedding switch

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: Not sure why but you can probably just launch `winword.exe` with `CreateProcess` and then attach to the running instance with `GetActiveObject` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-getactiveobject

Answer (score 2):

`CoCreateInstance()` is bound to create the instance exactly how Word is registered to be created. You can't change that behavior.

So, if you don't want `CoCreateInstance()` to use the registered parameters, your only option is to modify Word's registration in the Registry beforehand.  Which is likely to break how Word works, so don't do it.